# How to transfer data from one html page to another

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to HTML and javascript. So basically I have 2 HTML files

`a.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
    <!-- Some Stuff-->
    </head>
    <body>

    <script>
    </script>
    <!--In this part there is going to be a url of pdf. 
        I want that URL to be transferred to b.html 
        so that the same pdf could be shown.-->
    </body>
</html>
```

`b.html`

```
<html>
<!-- Code goes here-->
</html>
```

Comment: Transferred when? Javascript is event driven. What event will show page b and why show it with the same PDF? You can pass data in the URL, in local/sessionStorage or cookies (if same origin)

Comment: I forgot. The event will take place when the user clicks on b.html link on the a.html page

Comment: Hey @MinemanDev, welcome to SO. Your question is very vague at the moment and needs more specificity to determine what kind of solution you are looking for. For example: describe your outcome. Please modify your answer so that others can help you better.

Comment: Where is the link to page b and why do you want to show the same pdf on page b and why do you have to pass the pdf information to page b, does it not know it? `some stuff` is not a reasonable effort here at SO

Comment: Are the pages on the same domain? If so, use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Answer (score -1):

```
  <html>
  <head>
           <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"
```

src="asd.js">

```
  <body>

  <form name="form1" action="next.html" method="get">
  name:<input type ="text" id="name" name="n">
  <input type="submit" value="next" >
  <button type="button" id="print" onClick="testJS()"> Print </button>
  </form>

  </body>
  </html>




  <head>
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="asd.js"> 
     </script>
  </head>

  <body>


  function testJS()
  {

  var b = document.getElementById('name').value

   document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = b;

  }

  <form name="form1" action="next.html" method="get">
      <table>
   <tr>
    <td id="here">test</td>
 </tr>
   </table>
  </form>
```

Comment: Can you pls explain. What are the last 3 var. for?

Comment: Don’t accept an answer until it work as you expect. I do not see why this is a valid answer to your question. @AmiteshSingh please explain the code and format it proper